# PhantomJS doesn't support GZIP encoded content (for faster page loads)

Tags: encoding, http-headers, phantomjs, gzip

I've been learning how phantomjs works, and at some point i observed that it is taking more time to load given url using `page.open` method.

After digging out for solutions to this problem, i've found that using `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header increases the load speed by 3-8 times.

Now the problem is phantomjs fails to process the gzip encoded content by default or I may not know how to configure it properly to support gzip encoding (I tried taking screenshots in both cases; with and without gzip encoding, but with gzip encoding, i got weird image with lots of symbols and special characters)

When i use `cURL` or `file_get_contents` it is again faster than phantomjs for same url.
Now my questions are:

1. Do you guys have idea why phantomJS takes so much time to load a page ?
2. How to configure phantomJS so as to support gzip encoded responses ?

Here is my code:

```
 var page = require("webpage").create();
 page.viewportSize = {
   width: 1024,
   height: 768
 };

 var start = Date.now();
 page.customHeaders = {
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
   'Connection': 'keep-alive',
   'Accept-charset': 'utf-8'
 };
 page.open('http://facebook.com', function() {
   console.log('PhantomJS load time:', Date.now() - start);
   page.render('screenshot.png');
   phantom.exit();
 });
```

Comment: I wonder why you removed the syntax highlighting with your last edit.

Comment: Did you solve this?